# Black Box testing software

Tags: oracle, testing, black-box

We are about to get a canned package in that has been modified to our needs. I'm part of the team setup to prepare tests for it. It has an Oracle back end and I believe it's written in C++ .NET.

My question is what free or open source testing tools would you recommend.

Thanks

Ken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For regression testing of our applications I use a free tool called AutoHotKey http://www.autohotkey.com/. It is simple, batch configurable, and can work for virtually any application you have. Not exactly designed for black box testing, but a good free tool to add to your toolbox.

While there are a few good commercial applications for black box testing of applications (HoloDeck http://www.sisecure.com/holodeck/index.shtml, Cenzic Hailstorm http://www.cenzic.com/), the only open source applications that I know about only test network security (Spike http://www.immunitysec.com/resources-freesoftware.shtml, OWASP WebScarab http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project, and Nikto http://www.cirt.net/nikto2)

Answer (score 1):

Value checking. See if only valid dates are exempted, number fields except the full range, ect.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect from such a tool?  I don't know of any tool that can arbitrarily test any piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

For what is sounds like you already know what it is that you want to check.  Being a custom application your best bet would be to devise a test plan and manually test the values that you would like to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the others - since the application has been modified to your needs, you should make sure that it actually is *modified to your needs*.

If the assembly isn't obfuscated, you can use FxCop to analyze the binaries and see if there are any critical bugs (note - if you're not familiar with fxcop and static analysis, find someone who is before reporting a ton of bugs that won't be fixed).

Beyond that, you're looking at more techniques vs. tools to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Testing, either functional or non-functional, without reference to the
internal structure of the component or system.